# Issues with permissions when using ssh

Tags: networking, 16.04, permissions, ssh, openssh

I have been having some issues connecting via `ssh` between two computers.  Let us call them Desktop and Laptop.  Both are running Ubuntu 16.04 with a fresh install and with all updates applied.  When installing, I installed ssh and openssh.  These are the ssh packages installed:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep ssh

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libssh-4/xenial,now 0.6.3-4.3 amd64 [installed]
libssh-gcrypt-4/xenial,now 0.6.3-4.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libssh2-1/xenial,now 1.5.0-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openssh-client/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed]
openssh-server/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openssh-sftp-server/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ssh/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1 all [installed]
ssh-askpass-gnome/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed]
ssh-import-id/xenial,xenial,now 5.5-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
```

I can connect from Desktop to Laptop using `Desktop$ ssh -X username@laptop.address.ca` and no problems there.  However, using the mirror command on Laptop does not work.  That is: `Laptop$ ssh -X username@desktop.address.ca` does not work as it always returns the following after I input the proper password:

> Permission denied, please try again.

I am sitting next to both and can login directly without any issues either but not remotely from Laptop to Desktop (in that direction).

It is likely this has to do with folder or file permissions as opposed to issues with with the password but I have tried many things without success (e.g., deleting the .ssh folder on both systems, re-installing all ssh-related packages, and a couple of others).

Here is the final portion of the output of

```
$ssh -X username@desktop.address.ca

[BUNCH OF OUTPUT REMOVED]

username@desktop.address.ca's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
username@desktop.address.ca's password:
```

Can someone help.

Comment: Please add the output of `ssh -X username@desktop.address.ca -vvv` (at least the latter part containing the reason if it's too long).

Comment: There is a lot of text coming before the extra information I added.  However, it would require me to modify it a fair bit to avoid my machine and account being identified.